# Check whether a cell contains a link in Excel

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I am trying to check whether values in a column, say A, contain a link, and if true, in column B, I want to type a text, for example: link.
I have many records (10 000), so doing this by hand will take a lot of time. Thx.

Comment: Do you mean links to another cell within the worksheet/workbook or links to another workbook or a data connection? Have you tried anything?

Comment: The links are to external data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Save your file as .xlsm to allow Macros
- **Alt + F11** to open Visual Basic
- **Insert** -> **Module**
- Paste this function, it returns the count of hyperlinks in a range:

```
Function IsHyperlink(r As Range) As Integer
IsHyperlink = r.Hyperlinks.Count
End Function
```

- **Alt+Q**
- Use your new function with the if conditions to display your text:

  ```
   =IF(IsHyperlink(A1),"LINK","NO LINK")
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
Sub Links()
    Dim lnk As Hyperlink, lnks As Hyperlinks
    Set lnks = Range("A:A").Hyperlinks
    For i = 1 To lnks.Count
        Set lnk = lnks(i)
        lnk.Range.Value = "Link"
    Next
End Sub
```

You need to read more on VBA if you want to use the procedure above. Please also always share your research first and at least a code stub. This was simple hence the exception.

Answer (score 0):

There is a formula that could work, but it's based upon the length of the characters in the cell.  For example, a hyperlink typically contains more characters due to the pathname.  If the number of characters in your cells is always less than 30, for example, then you could write the formula

```
 =If(Len(Cell("Filename",A1))>30,"True","False")
```

The formula will return "True" if the cell is a hyperlink.
This formula assumes that the Excel file is stored in a subfolder where each folder name is referenced which adds to the length of the hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

An aproximate solution without VBA:

```
=AND(ISREF(A1),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("http",A1,1)))
```

It is based on asking for two conditions:

1. There is reference in the cell (it applies for both hyperlinks and internal references)
2. The cell text (the link) contains the string "http", to cover both http and https

Answer (score 0):

As links (if we are speaking about links, not hyperlinks) are formulas, this should work (unless you also have formulas without links):

```
=IF(ISFORMULA(A1),"LINK","")
```

Answer (score -5):

I managed to find a formula, not on VBA.

I used `=IF(HYPERLINK(A1>0), "WEB", "")`

Thank you all for your time. :)

Comment: HYPERLINK(A1>0) will return a hyperlink and it only checks if the A1 is greater than zero or not, and it doesn't check if the A1 is a hyperlink